# Sass throwing errors about things it should not

Tags: css, sass

The error is:

> Invalid CSS after "": expected media query list, was ""only screen
>   an..."

The relevant code before that is:

```
$mobile-screen: emCalc(768px) !default;
$mobile: "only screen and (max-width:"#{$mobile-screen}")" !default;
```

The code inline is: `@media #{$mobile}`

When I switch out the variables it compiles without error, however once I changed it back and it started working anyway. There are bunch of other errors after that as well.

So there must be a flaw in my Sass compiler. Does anyone have any ideas what the flaw could be?

Comment: Sass is telling you that you have a parse error.  That means there is a flaw in your code, not a flaw in the Sass compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media

You should consider rewriting your code like this:

```
$media: only screen;
$feature: max-width;
$value: emCalc(768px) !default;

@media #{$media} and ($feature: $value) {

}
```

[Here is a nice article on the topic](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32)

From what i read, the `max-width:"#{$mobile-screen}")"` is using the same syntax as [SASS Maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps), causing all the trouble.

Comment: I could change the code, however even when I fix this, there will be several errors similar to this. The code is not written by me and other people supposedly can compile it.

Comment: Then you should check your sass version and possible install an update.

Comment: I can not help you with that. The only thing i know is: When you enter all the code you provided with your question, here: http://sassmeister.com/ the compiler will fail. When you enter the provided solution it works. Good luck anyways.

Comment: I tried installing older version of Sass and the compiler worked. So I  guess I will just use that. Thank you for your help

Comment: @HenriErilaid - If you can identify the Sass compiler versions which were failing and working, then you could post that as an answer in case someone else has the same problem.